# Assign default values to nested objects when server JSON response doesn't contain key for that in Moshi?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, moshi

I'm using `Moshi` to parse `JSON` responses to `JAVA` objets. Problem is when the server doesn't send key-value for a nested class, moshi is assigning it to `null`.
While assigning the default values to primitives and String etc. works, instantiating the nested class is not working.

Parent Customer class -

```
public class Customer {
    @Json(name = "id")
    Integer id;
    @Json(name = "test")
    String test = "I'm batman!";
    @Json(name = "default_address")
    Address defaultAddress = new Address(-1, -1);

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }
}
```

Address class -

```
public class Address {
    @Json(name = "id")
    Integer id;
    @Json(name = "customer_id")
    Integer customerId;

    public Address(int id, int cusID) {
        this.id = id;
        this.customerId = cusID;
    }

    public Integer getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

While the response doesn't contain any key with the name `test`, it works. But when the server doesn't send `default_address` key, `defaultAddress` is set to `null`.

Comment: It's normal in java. Default value of `Object` is `null`. You have to check `defaultAddress` is `null` or not before using it's property

Comment: But I instantiated it, `Address defaultAddress = new Address(-1, -1);`

Comment: @Md. Asaduzzaman That's exactly what I don't want to do, I don't want to put numerous null checks in my adapters. I want to assign default values to all `Customer` class fields.

Comment: Initially I have missed the default initialization. Now I have checked with your code in Moshi v1.8.0 and it's working fine. I just use: **{"id": 5}**

Comment: I'm using v1.5.0, I'll try with the latest version. Thank you. Yes, I have the getter, just removed here for brevity.